# I altered the partition table (resized the root and created a new partition and formatted it) but can't log into my arch system anymore

Tags: arch-linux, boot-loader, root-filesystem, partition-table, mkfs

Yesterday, I had an idea of having two root partitions for my arch system, one which would contain packages and system files and another one to store my personal files (music, videos, etc).
With that thought in my mind, I plugged in my arch-linux bootable usb flash drive into my PC and booted up the live-iso.

Using cfdisk, I resized my main linux-file-system partition (the root partition, i.e, on /dev/sda1) to about half it's size (100G) and created another partition of 100G (on /dev/sda2), altered/wrote the partition table and then formatted the newly created partition on /dev/sda2 using: `mkfs.ext4 -L root /dev/sda2`

But, after rebooting, 'arch' device won't boot and returns to the bios immediately after selecting it from the F12 (Select Boot Device) BIOS menu (it was supposed to show the grub bootloader after selecting 'arch' from F12 menu).

Do I need to reset my partition table and again install arch from scratch? It wouldn't be a trouble for me to install arch-linux again as I installed it on a new hard disk, but I need to learn why this happened and what mistake have I have, so that I could fix it myself if it happens in future.

**My System Specifications (if required):**

- CPU: Intel Pentium G2030
- GPU: Intel HD Graphics (rare edition, doesn't has any number like HD 4000 or 2000 or like that)
- RAM: 2GB DDR3 1600Mhz Single Channel (⁠٥-_-⁠)
- Dedicated-GPU: None ⁠[⁠-⁠_⁠-⁠]
- Hard-Disk: WD Green 500GB 7200RPM HDD

Comment: did you shrink the filesystem at all?

Comment: Yes, I think so. I shrinked the main root partition which contains the OS by 50% and made another partition using that free space.

Comment: "two root partitions for my arch system". As I see it, that would need to be a root partition and a `/home` partition. If you made them both root partition, than it is logical that it will not work.

Comment: shrinking partitions (cfdisk, or other partition tool) and shrinking filesystems (resize2fs, or other filesystem tools) are two different matters. some programs do it for you (gparted, lvresize --resizefs, ...) but most of the time it's up to you.

Comment: I understand now. I've actually shrinked the partition and made two 'root' partitions. Maybe, that has resulted in my main partition getting corrupted. I actually needed to make a root and a /home partition, just like @LjmDullaart said. But, instead I made two root partitions, which worsened the matter. Well, now that I know my mistake, I guess I would format my drive and install a fresh copy from scratch. Thank you ljmdullaart and frostschutz for helping me find my mistake and sparing your time to look into my problem. Have a Great Day!

Comment: BTW, How can I mark this question as solved? I checked the FAQ and it said I needed to check mark an answer as the correct answer, but couldnt find those options. Only an option to flag comments is available here.

Comment: You don't mark questions as solved. You can accept an answer but at the time of this writing there isn't one. If you want you can answer your own question but please make it with quality standards and useful for the community at large. Hint: Answers like "my bad, did something dumb, gonna reinstall" aren't worth the effort.